# Page numbers (Roman number and Arabic numerals) in ConTeXt

Tags: context, page-numbering, roman-numerals

My simple document is divided into only two parts (it's only some math notes).

```
\starttext
% frontmatter
\startstandardmakeup
... % the cover
\stopstandardmakeup
\completecontent
\startbodymatter
... % main part
\stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

I hope that the page number in `frontmatter` can be `Roman numbers` which start from the contents `not the standardmakeup` so I can achieve this by this:

```
\startfrontmatter
...
\stopstandardmakeup
\setupuserpagenumber[numberconversion=romannumerals]
\completecontent
\stopfrontmatter
\startbodymatter
% some settings?
...
```

and I also hope that the page numbers in `bodypart` can be from `Arabic numeral 1`, how can I achieve this?

more clearly: when ConTeXt enters the `bodymatter`, can I reset the page numbers so that it can start from 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain roman page numbers for the front part you can either use

```
\definestructureconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]
```

or

```
\startsectionblockenvironment [frontpart]
  \setupuserpagenumber [numberconversion=romannumerals]
\stopsectionblockenvironment
```

Commands that need to be invoked at the body part use the same mechanism, just
replace `frontpart` with `bodypart` and use `\setcounter` to change the page
number:

```
\startsectionblockenvironment [bodypart]
  \setcounter [userpage] [1]
\stopsectionblockenvironment
```

Here a full example:

```
\definestructureconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]

\startsectionblockenvironment [bodypart]
  \setcounter [userpage] [1]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\starttext
  \startstandardmakeup
    Cover page
  \stopstandardmakeup
  \startfrontmatter
    \completecontent
  \stopfrontmatter
  \startbodymatter
    Main part
  \stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```