# Book style page numbering with ConTeXt

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, context

1. I would like to set the numbering like

   - Cover page = show no page number
   - TOC = roman page numbers
   - Body= arabic page numbers

   Many people have previously asked similar question like [Page numbers (Roman number and Arabic numerals) in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108676/page-numbers-roman-number-and-arabic-numerals-in-context), however the answers seems to work with when we rely on default page numbering style.

   However when I modify the template shown in the above example with `\setupfootertext`, the numbering stops working. Below is the `tex` file.
2. Looking to hide the footer till I reach the body
3. Have footer, with alternative pages showing the title and the chapter name. Both pages with arabic numbers.

.

```
% Template from the line provide above
\definestructureconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]

\startsectionblockenvironment [bodypart]
  \setcounter [userpage] [1]
\stopsectionblockenvironment


%=========================ADDITION====================================
\setuppagenumbering[location=,alternative=doublesided]

\setupfootertexts[\setups{text right}][][][\setups{text left}]

\startsetups[text right]
  \rlap{}
  \hfill
  \bf {\sl Title goes here }
  \hfill
  \llap{\pagenumber}
\stopsetups

\startsetups[text left]
  \rlap{\pagenumber}
  \hfill
  \bf \cap{ Chapter \getmarking[chapternumber] }  \getmarking[chapter]
  \hfill
  \llap{}
\stopsetups
%=========================ADDITION END====================================
\starttext
  \startstandardmakeup
    Cover page
  \stopstandardmakeup
  \startfrontmatter
    \completecontent
  \stopfrontmatter

  \startbodymatter

    \section[production]{Production}
      Production is a two part process.
    \section[background]{Background}

  \stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Just saw [Roman numeral numbering for introductions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/741/roman-numeral-numbering-for-introductions?rq=1). Would have a look if `book` class would help.

Comment: Change `\pagenumber` to `\userpagenumber`.

Comment: @Aditya Want to make that an answer and get it off the unanswered list? Thanks.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ConTeXt has two notions of page numbers: The real page number (accessed using `\pagenumber`) and the user page number (accessed using `\userpagenumber`). The `userpagenumber` is meant for what you are looking for (different page numbering in frontpart and bodypart.

In the code you posted, in the `sectionblock` environment you are resetting the `userpage` counter; but in the footer you are using `\pagenumber`. To view the correct numbers, use `\userpagenumber` in the footers as well.

Answer (score 1):

A more general answer follows.
Under mkii to start somewhere the first page: `\setuppagenumber[number=1]`
and under mkiv: `\setcounter[userpage][1]`.